# Firefox 3.6/4: modify/ tweak spell-check dictionary?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, spell-check, firefox-extensions

I edit frequently on Super User, and it is a pain to edit for capitalization or words that are shortened, i.e. `Win7` instead of `Windows 7`, or `windows` versus `Windows`.

Using Firefox 3.6 and/or 4, Is there a way (using an extension or configure settings) I can configure the dictionary to automatically recognize words that may not be capitalized or are shortened (while editing a post)?

Say, have the dictionary see `Win7` and underline it so that I can right-click on it, and select `Windows 7`?  I would want it to be configurable, so I can tell it what to look for, etc...

Ideas or recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I present you [FoxReplace](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/6510/), a Firefox extension (4.0b8pre) that can replace single words or whole phrases individually or automatically using custom filters.

Comment: are you the author?